# How can I search for the options for a particular property of a plotly figure?

Tags: python, plotly

**The question**

In the figure below, the jagged shape of the line is set using `'hvh'` as an argument for the `shape` property of the line. As a specific example for a more general case, let's say that I've forgotten which porperty (or properites) that take `'hvh'` as an argument. How can I search through the entire plotly figure to find it?

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
#imports
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Notebook settings
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# Some sample data
x = np.random.normal(50, 5, 500)
binned = np.histogram(x, bins=25, density=True)
plot_y = np.cumsum(binned[0])

# Line
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=binned[1],
    y=plot_y,
    mode='lines',
    name="X",
    hoverinfo='all',
    line=dict(color = 'rgb(1255, 0, 0)', shape='hvh'
    )
)

data = [trace1]

# Layout
layout = dict(title = 'Where is hvh?',
    legend=dict(
        y=0.5,
        traceorder='reversed',
        font=dict(
            size=16
        )
    )
)

# Make figure
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

# Plot
iplot(fig, filename='line-shapes')
```

**The details:**

The shape is obtained using `line=dict(color = 'rgb(1255, 0, 0)', shape='hvh'`. And if you simply run `fig`, it will return a dict where you can see where the argument is applied to the figure:

```
{'data': [Scatter({
      'hoverinfo': 'all',
      'line': {'color': 'rgb(1255, 0, 0)', 'shape': 'hvh'},
      'mode': 'lines',
      'name': 'X',
      'x': array([35.36954648,
[...]
```

Let's say that I'd like to know what other propoerties of a an iplot figure that can take `'hvh'` or any other string as an argument, how can I search for that? I happen to know that `'hvh'` shows up in the output from `help(trace1['line'])`

```
shape
 |      Determines the line shape. With "spline" the lines are drawn
 |      using spline interpolation. The other available values
 |      correspond to step-wise line shapes.
 |      
 |      The 'shape' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
 |        - One of the following enumeration values:
 |              ['linear', 'spline', 'hv', 'vh', 'hvh', 'vhv']
```

But if `'hvh'` were to occure for several shapes, It would be extremely hard to look through the output from `help()` for every possible property. If I was looking for `'shape'` itself, I could just run a search on [plot.ly/python/reference/](https://plot.ly/python/reference/) and get:

[image]

But that is not the case for `'hvh'` or `hvh`:

[image]

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use your in-browser ctl-F to search within the page at https://plot.ly/python/reference/ if the search box isn't giving you what you need.

That said, I've just updated our search index to include the list of accepted values in enumerated attributes, so as of 2 minutes ago, searching for "hvh" gives:

[image]